# How to switch console mode to GUI mode on RHEL7?

Tags: rhel

I load the RHEL 7.2, I forget to select the options before loading OS, after my machine booted through console mode `runlevel 3`, I installed some dependency package, after reboot I got GUI mode, but after every reboot machine I get console mode then I run the command `init 5` for GUI mode.

My question is how to set `runlevel 5` to default?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
runlevel --> will give you your current runlevel
```

to list all currently loaded targets we ca use the following command:

```
systemctl list-units -t target
```

Next, we can list all available runlevel targets using a below command:

```
systemctl list-units -t target -a
```

for activating the ***runlevel 5*** run this

```
systemctl enable graphical.target --force
```